# Matrices of difent size multiplication

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Good evenning

In Rstudio

I have a problem multiplying these two matrices of a different size, and it becomes worse because I have to multiply in such a way that the values in the row d2$ID=1 have to multiply **only** the repetitions of w$sample=1.

*sample and ID are indicating is the same sample*

In other words, from the "subset" d2$ID=1, every single value ("L1", "ST", "GR", "CB", "HSK", "DDM") has to multiply the whole "subset" w$sample=1 (4 rows in this case, but not always), yes, all the values "G2", "G4", "G6", "G8", "G12"

```
>d2
   ID    L1      ST           GR        CB         HSK         DDM
1   1 0.1662000 0.2337000 0.3637000 0.11110000 0.10100000   0.024300000
2   2 0.1896576 0.2280830 0.3705740 0.09406879 0.09319434   0.024422281
3   3 0.1110259 0.2217769 0.4180797 0.11122498 0.10902635   0.028866094
4   4 0.1558785 0.2008862 0.4222565 0.09805538 0.10218119   0.020742172
5   5 0.1536421 0.1674096 0.4205395 0.14362176 0.08635519   0.028431849
6   6 0.1841964 0.1514189 0.4603306 0.10243621 0.08928011   0.012337688
```

```
> w
           sample   G2      G4      G6      G8      G12
1              1    10.9    15.9    21.4    28.0    37.8
2              1    11.5    16.6    22.2    29.5    38.3
3              1    10.3    15.1    20.7    28.3    36.7
4              1    11.7    18.1    24.8    31.2    39.5
5              2    11.0    16.8    22.4    30.6    38.0
6              2    10.1    15.9    22.5    30.2    36.7
7              2    12.8    17.8    22.8    28.7    37.1
8              2    11.8    16.3    20.8    27.3    34.7
9              2    11.9    16.7    21.6    28.3    34.6
10             3    12.0    18.1    24.2    30.9    40.0
11             3    12.2    17.7    24.2    31.7    40.5
12             4    11.1    16.5    22.7    31.0    39.2
13             4    12.5    19.8    27.4    32.8    38.8
14             4    12.4    19.2    25.8    33.0    39.9
15             4    12.4    19.2    26.2    33.4    38.9
16             4    13.4    18.3    23.7    30.0    38.2
17             5    13.3    18.6    24.0    30.7    38.4
18             5    13.3    18.1    22.9    30.1    36.8
19             5    13.7    19.9    26.5    33.8    43.0
20             5    12.7    18.2    24.6    32.5    41.3
21             6    12.1    17.5    24.3    33.7    42.2
22             6    14.5    20.8    28.4    35.3    43.7
```

I have check already a lot of questions but I can't figure it out,  specially because most of the information is for matrices of the same size.

I tried by filtering the data from d2, but the data set is really big, then is really inefficient.

I am a beginner, if you consider is so easy I would appreciate at least a hint, please! 
I have several data sets like these ones...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many values are you expecting from `"every single value ("L1", "ST", "GR", "CB", "HSK", "DDM") has to multiply the whole "subset" w$sample=1`? You have 5 and 6 items. Are you expecting 30 values for each line of d2?

Comment: Yes, I am expecting 30 values for each line of d2. 

Note: The 1st line of d2 (ID=1), has to multiply the 4 lines corresponding to w$sample=1 and so on and so forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to perform as requested:

```
res <- apply(w, 1, function(x){ unclass(
                      outer(as.matrix( x[-1] ), 
                            as.matrix( d2[1, c( "L1", "ST", "GR", "CB", "HSK", "DDM")])))})
str(res)

# result
# num [1:30, 1:22] 1.81 2.64 3.56 4.65 6.28 ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ : NULL
#  ..$ : chr [1:22] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

I almost got it right on the first pass but after some debugging found that I needed to add the as.matrix call to both arguments inside outer (so to speak ;-). To explain my logic   ... I wanted to run down each row of w with `apply` and then use `match` on the value of the first column (of each row of w) to the unique row of d2. The `match` function is designed for just this purpose, to return a suitable number to be used for indexing. Then with the rest of the row (`x[-1]` by the time it was passed through the function call), I would use `outer` on the row values crossed with the desired row and columns of `d2`. If you do it without the as.matrix calls you get an error message:

```
Error in tcrossprod(x, y) : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

I don't think that's a very informative error message. Both of the arguments were numeric vectors.

Comment: Thank you for your time

Comment: Thank you for your time
I did try but somehow I did it wrong because it doesn't work. I ran:

`f <- str( apply(w, 1, function(x){ unclass(
  outer(as.matrix( x[-1] ), 
        as.matrix( d2[1, c( "L1", "ST", "GR", "CB", "HSK", "DDM")])))}) )`
And all that I obtained was: 
 `num  num [1:30, 1:22] 1.81 2.64 3.56 4.65 6.28 ...`

I don't find any way yo access the outcome ¿? print, View, head, etc, are not working

Comment: Did you assign it to a name?

Comment: Yes I did, but also exactly as you posted

Comment: Assigned to "f <-" But I also tried as you posted and gives me: `num [1:30, 1:22] 1.81 2.64 3.56 4.65 6.28 ...` I don't find the way to access. 

In your code, is `attr` used to access? they kept giving me an error
` - attr(f, "L1")
- attr(f, "L1") <- c(2, 5)
attr(f,"dimnames")=List of(2, 5)
attr(*,"dimnames")=List of 2
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
- attr(f, "dimnames")=List of 2
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2 `

Comment: I apologize. I used `str` to show the structure of the result but meant for you to assign the result of the apply call to a vlaue.

Comment: ¡GRACIAS!
Excellent! it works perfectly... I am already working on the new data base!! :)